# Custom order in ng-repeat to sort the specific data only

Tags: angularjs

May be my question would be duplicate but after lots of research i am unable to find a solution in angularjs.

I have a table data like following

[image]

I want to sort the data in this way that employees with score "0" will always gravitate to the bottom, regardless of sort order. I tried with custom filter but not getting any solution. It may have simple logic but since i am new to angularjs and don't have much logic of it.

Comment: logic is not related with angularjs, custom filter in angular is the solution. you can do reverse sort based on score in your custom filter.

Comment: Please show us the code from your attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter ones without '0' and add then at the top of the table and apply sorting to this list. Filter the ones with '0' and add the bottom of the table. So you will have 2 ng-repeat instead of one that you have now.